# Linking workflow to a custom form in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I'm a relatively new sharepoint user using 2007!

I have a built a list, and using designer customised a user input form for completion.  The data submitted on the form is built over a period of time and when complete, needs to be used different activities which need to be manually triggered by the user.

My user process is as follows: user completes info on new form at stage one, user updates information and completes information on edit form at step 2 (this step may be repeated if not all data available) which links to a display form to review before submission of workflows.  It's from this form I need to link to the workflow initiation screen.

I have 2 x oob approval workflows set on the list, and want to navigate the user from the form to the workflow initiation screen so that they choose which workflow they want to send and when.  using one of the list fields, I have populated the URL to this screen for each list ID.

However it has a & within the path so when I try to pull this data through to the form it changes this to &amp, and breaks the link! any idea of how I can work around this?

I would add, I have very little knowledge outside of sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;` is the html representation of an `&`, it wouldn't translate in the URL.

When you populate the URL, you can try replacing the `&` with `%26` as that is the ASCII Hex code for `&`, it may work.

Hope this helps?